# How can I show an intent chooser even though there is only one app?

Tags: android

`Intent.createChooser()` will directly open an app if there is only one which can handle the intent. My question is how can I show the chooser dialog even though there is only one app?

Comment: make Custom Intent chooser for it.

Comment: why would you want that? It just adds an extra action even though there is only 1 choice

Comment: @Sagar Jethva Do I need to write my own layout file and query the packages and create a dialog?

Comment: @Tim Castelijns Some apps can open all kinds of files even though they can't deal with that file.